# Proving that the set of all integers cannot be a vector space whatever the fields are

Tags: linear-algebra

Let Z be the set of all integers. Prove that there doesn't exist a field F and a way to define
a scalar multiplication on Z over F such that Z is a vector space over F (the vector
addition is the usual addition)

Comment: A finite field has a finite (prime) characteristic and $\Bbb Z$ has no torsion. So $\Bbb Q \subseteq F$ must hold and $\Bbb Z$ is not divisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume there is a field $F$ such that $\mathbb Z/F$ is a vector space.
Let $e$ be the field's multiplicative identity and $\theta$ its additive identity (i.e. its zero).
Denote the elements of $\mathbb Z$ by their integer representation.
Apply the standard vector space principles and integer addition.....
$e.1 = 1$
$1 + 1 = 2 = e.1 + e.1 = (e + e).1$
So, there is some element $\alpha = e + e \in F$ that satisfies $\alpha.1 = 2$, and $\alpha \ne \theta $ because $\theta.1 = 0 $
Then $\alpha $ has a field inverse $\beta = e/\alpha$
By closure then $\beta.1 \in \mathbb Z$ and is therefore an integer.
Also, $ 1 = e. 1 = \alpha.\beta. 1 = (e + e).\beta.1 = e.\beta.1 + e.\beta.1 = \beta.e.1 + \beta.e.1 = \beta.1 + \beta.1$
So, $\beta.1$ must be an integer, say $p$, which satisfies $p + p = 1$
This is a contradiction, so there is no such field.

Comment: This is just an additional question. It seems that we say nothing about the characteristic of the field, but this proof requires F does not have charactersitc 2, right?

Comment: No, it avoids that as a requirement. Specifically, it relies on the *vector space* property that $\theta.v = 0$ to show that $\alpha.1 = 2 \implies \alpha \ne \theta$ and hence that $\alpha$ has a multiplicative inverse.   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_(algebra) Showing that $\alpha = e + e \ne \theta$ shows at this stage in the proof that $F$ cannot have characteristic $2$.